# How to use shouldSelectItemAt while waiting for user input from an alert?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to delay the selection of an item from a collection view until the user has answered a question in a popup alert.

In this scenario - when I have a timer running I want a popup to ask if they really want to switch to a new timer (which they selected in the collection view) and stop the timer that is currently running.

However - the return happens before the user can respond. Any help would be great.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    {
        var changeTimer: Bool = false

        if isTimerRunning {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Switch Timers?", message: "Change timers now?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in                
                changeTimer = true
                // more code
            })

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { _ in
                changeTimer = false                
            })

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            changeTimer = true
            // more code
        }

        return changeTimer
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not wait with `shouldSelectItemAt` but you can use helper method as shown below:

First of all update your `shouldSelectItemAt` method like below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    if isTimerRunning {
        showConfirmationPopUp(indexPath: indexPath)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

then add `showConfirmationPopUp` method:

```
func showConfirmationPopUp(indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Switch Timers?", message: "Change timers now?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in
        // more code
        self.myCollectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(self.myCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { _ in

    })

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now once user click `Yes` option your `didSelectItemAt` will call.

But you can ignore

```
self.myCollectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(self.myCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
```

If you don't want to call `didSelectItemAt` and you can make your modifications for that selected cell in `Yes` action handler directly as you have `indexPath` in your `showConfirmationPopUp` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely set the selection of the collectionView to none and inside

```
var currentSelected:Int?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool

  // show alert and in success part reload the collectionView  

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Switch Timers?", message: "Change timers now?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { _ in                

            self.currentSelected =  indexPath.item

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { _ in 
        })

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Then inside `cellForItemAt`

```
 if indexPath.item == currentSelected {
    // color it
 else {
    // not selected 
 }
```